# pick and omit in one function (lodash) in Redux action object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

Basically what I need is to get "items" from json and re-assign it, and leave other keys untouched:
The first approach duplicates data.
The second seems to be bad in terms of performance.
And the third is hard to read and understand.
I use lodash. But if it can't be done in a clever fashion, you can suggest me a different library.

```
function a(name, json) {
    return {
        type: RECEIVE_DATA,
        name,
        items: _.get(json, 'data.items', []),
        receivedAt: Date.now(),
        ...json,
    };
}

function b(name, json) {
    return {
        ..._.omit(json, 'data'),
        type: RECEIVE_DATA,
        name,
        items: _.get(json, 'data.items', []),
        receivedAt: Date.now(),
    }
}

function c(name, json) {
    return {
        ..._.transform(json, (result, value, key) =>{
            if (key === 'data') {
                result['items'] = value['items'];
            } else {
                result[key] = value;
            }
        }, {}),
        type: RECEIVE_DATA,
        name,
        receivedAt: Date.now(),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use parameters [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get `items`, and [rest properties](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread) to collect the rest of the params:

```js
const json = { another: [], data: { items: [1] } };

function a(name, { data, data: { items = [] }, ...jsonRest } = {}) {
  return {
    type: 'RECEIVE_DATA',
    name,
    items,
    receivedAt: Date.now(),
    ...jsonRest
  };
}
            
console.log(a('name', json));
```

You can also shorten the action creator a bit by using an arrow function:

```
const a = (name, { data, data: { items = [] }, ...jsonRest } = {}) => ({
    type: RECEIVE_DATA,
    name,
    items,
    receivedAt: Date.now(),
    ...jsonRest
});
```

Comment: So many people using spread object syntax now. Is it confirmed anywhere that JavaScript will actually be getting it?

Comment: [It is a Stage 3 proposal for ECMAScript.](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread), and a very popular feature, so I think that it will. Even if not, we we'll always have Babel.

Comment: Parameter destructuring is supported by all the mayor browsers now: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-destructuring,_parameters (unless you want to target IE11, but in that case the question example uses object spread which is not in IE11 either)

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind having a couple more lines in your function, you could easily just grab the data from that key then `delete` it:

```
function a(name, json = {}) {
    const { items = [] } = json.data;
    delete json.data;
    return {
        type: RECEIVE_DATA,
        name,
        items,
        receivedAt: Date.now(),
        ...json,
    };
}
```

Comment: Accessing 'json.data' is dangerous, because it might be absent!

Comment: @SashaTobin I updated my answer to contain a default object value for `json`, if `json` is an object then there is no danger to using this. If `json` is undefined or not an object then it would fail (without the default argument)

Comment: Mutating a parameter for this is a bad idea: `a(name, json); c(name, json)` may break if you expect `json` to remain the same.